# Plotting a Stochastic function

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I have a stochastic function and I tried to plot it in Mathematica

```
C1 = 100;
C2 = 150;
P = 500;
M = 10000;
n = 100 + 10*a;
B = 2500;
Plot[B*n + Integrate[((-C1)*x)*PDF[NormalDistribution[n*a, Sqrt[n]*2], x], {x, 0, n*a}] + Integrate[(P*(x - n*a) - C1*x)*PDF[NormalDistribution[n*a, Sqrt[n]*2], x], 
{x, n*a, M}] + Integrate[(P*(x - n*a) - C2*x)*PDF[NormalDistribution[n*a, Sqrt[n]*2], x], {x, M, Infinity}], {a, 0, 15}, Filling -> Bottom]
```

The output comes like this
[image: Plot Output]

Does it mean that the function is discontinuous at some points and how to rectify it? I had tried taking the limit of from 0 to 15 which gives me a smooth curve

[image: Modo]

Comment: Please share your minimal working code example formatted in [Raw InputForm](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/menuitem/RawInputForm.html) intead of Notebook Boxes.  See this [Meta Q&A](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2670/10397). It's very hard to read `\!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(0\), \(n*a\)]\(\((\(-C1\)*x)\)*`.

Comment: Please check now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

C1 = 100;
C2 = 150;
P = 500;
M = 10000;
n = 100 + 10*a;
B = 2500;

pdf[a_, x_] = 
 PDF[NormalDistribution[n*a, Sqrt[n]*2], x] // FullSimplify

(* E^(-((-10 a (10 + a) + x)^2/(80 (10 + a))))/
   (4 Sqrt[10 + a] Sqrt[5 π])

int[a_] = B*n + 
   Integrate[((-C1)*x)*pdf[a, x], {x, 0, n*a}] + 
   Integrate[(P*(x - n*a) - C1*x)*pdf[a, x], {x, n*a, M}] + 
      Integrate[(P*(x - n*a) - C2*x)*pdf[a, x], {x, M, Infinity}] //
  FullSimplify[#, a >= 0] &

(* 50 (10 (20 - 3 a) a + 20 (250 + Sqrt[10 + a] Sqrt[5/π]) + 
   2 Sqrt[10 + 
     a] (-2 E^(-(5/4) a^2 (10 + a)) - 
      E^(-((5 (-1000 + a (10 + a))^2)/(4 (10 + a))))) Sqrt[5/π] + 
   5 a (10 + a) (2 Erfc[1/2 Sqrt[5] a Sqrt[10 + a]] + 
      Erfc[(Sqrt[5] (-1000 + a (10 + a)))/(2 Sqrt[10 + a])])) *)
```

**EDIT:** To add the maximum

```
{max, arg} = NMaximize[int[a], a]

(* {311533., {a -> 7.57523}} *)

Plot[int[a], {a, 0, 15},
 Filling -> Bottom,
 WorkingPrecision -> 20,
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4],
   Point[{a /. arg, max}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: After defining the function "pdf" you used that in the function to plot?

Comment: Can you add the entire code here? I think some part of your code is missing.

Comment: All of the code is there. The `pdf` is present in each of the integrals in the definition of `int`

Comment: Thanks. Can I get the plot of the function without giving the values of parameters like P, C1, C2 etc. just to find out the nature of the function?

Comment: You cannot plot a function with an undefined variable. You could  use `Plot3D` to plot against both `a` and one other `variable` of your choosing.

Comment: Thanks, I have already tried that and got the output. Thanks again for your help

Comment: One more question.. Can I add the maximum point in the plot you have shown just to show where the maximum happens?